# Function to create properties of an object?

Tags: javascript, function, object, properties, set

I'm new to javascript and I'm trying to code a game.

I need to create an object that stocks the height of 10 "columns". These columns must be set to zero. so I need something like this :

var columnLevel = {c1 : 0, c2 : 0, c3 : 0, c4 : 0 etc...}

but that's not practical, especially because I might need to have more columns at some point.

How do I create some sort of function that automatically sets n columns to zero ?

Thank you for your time

Corentin

Comment: simple for loop and bracket notation.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    columnLevel[`c${i}`] = 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//function that returns a new Object of n columns
function Columns(colsNum) {
//empty object
        const newColumns={};
//adding n consecutive values
        for(let i=0; i<colsNum;i++){
           newColumns["c"+i]=0;
        }
        return newColumns;
    }
// 5 columns
const col1= new Columns(5);   
//25 !!! columns
const col2= new Columns(25);
//write to console just to check if as expected
console.log(col2);
console.log(col1);
```